# initWithContentsOfURL:error: returns (null) when the contents are special characters

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, encoding, nsstring

`initWithContentsOfURL:error:` returns `(null)` when it should return `"São Tomé and Príncipe"`. I've tested it using text without special characters, and then it worked fine.

```
NSString *myURL = [NSString stringWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com/api-call.php"];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:myURL];
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",strResult);
```

I guess the problem is related with the encoding, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: It's returning `nil`, not the string `(null)`. Have you inspected the error object to see what it says? `NSError * err; NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err]; if( !strResult ){ NSLog(@"%@", err); }`

Comment: No, I'll try that now. Thanks

Comment: It returns: "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261". Looks like I'll have to check if the API is returning in UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Iulius Caesar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603977/iulius-caesar) I found out that my document wasn't returning data in UTF-8 encoding.

I've modified the php file by adding `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` to the top of the code and saving it as UTF-8 formated file. Now it works!